# Loading lightbox with double click

Tags: jquery, lightbox

Is it possible to set lightbox so that it shows the expanded picture when it is double clicked/tapped rather than single click/tap?

Update:

I am using the code below to disable the click command on the links and make them react to a double click instead:

```
        $('a', this).each(function () {
          $(this).click(function () {
            return false;
          }).dblclick(function () {                
            window.location = this.href;
            return false;
          });
        });
```

However, all I am getting is a page load with the picture instead of the lightbox functionality that loads the picture overlay. How can I call the Lightbox functionality from a javascript/jquery function?

Answer (score 0):

Jquery offers a dblclick event handler

http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

Javascript offers a ondblclick listener

http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/event-attributes/ondblclick

Update:

I see, Lokesh's Lighbox (I'm assuming is the one you are using, since there are several) is intrinsically connected to the single click event, you can see that on lines 49-55.

github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/blob/master/js/lightbox.js

The approach you are trying will only sort half of the problem which is to cancel the single click activation. The 'dblclick' part is doing exactly what you want it to, that is, opening the image on the window itself.

There is no code anywhere triggering the Lightbox on that event.

There are three things you could do:
(i) Modify lighbox, just changing the event on line 51 should work.
(ii) Use a different plugin, one that accepts options.
(iii) Create a view controller that initialises the LB params and simulates a click to trigger it.

Solution (i) has the caveat that prevents you from updating to new versions as they come without modifying the code yourself but since the change is trivial, may not be a problem. Solution (iii) is ugly and I don't recommend it but it's there for completeness' sake.

Comment: Yes, but my problem is, how do I disable the loading of the lightbox on click and make it load with a double click? The way lightbox works (at least the part I know) is by placing the picture as the target URL of a hyperlink. Perhaps I did not explain myself properly, but what I really need is for that particular hyperlink to be triggered by a double click and not a single click.

Alternately I need to find a way to fire the lightbox functionality through a javascript function rather through the click event that occurs on a hyperlink.

Comment: I ended up creating my own cut down version of lightbox. No fancy animations but at least it works.